# Checking for elements in Dataframe output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I created a python code to extract some data and I set certain conditions. Now, I want to check my output to see if my conditions have been processed correctly.
For i.e I want to know if a number of accounts appear in my output. Following is what I did but doesn't seem to be right.

```
account = 502-4549643
if account in df:
    print('Element exists in df')
```

Comment: Dataframe is a 2-dimentional object with several columns. Try specifying exact column you are searching in.

Comment: and you know that `502-4549643` is an calcaulation, right? it will look for an `int` of `-4549141` and not for the string `"502-4549643"` in `df`

Answer (score 0):

Condition check should be `if account in df['<<ACCOUNT_COLUMN_NAME>>'].tolist()`